# How do I send a PUT request in ZendFramework2?

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

I'm trying to figure out how to send the parameters in a PUT request. I have a javascript interface that works great, so I know the server-side works, but my unit tests never send the PUT parameters correctly. Here's what I've tried:

```
$this->request->getQuery()->set("id", $id);
$params = array(
        'attribute' => 'email',
        'email' => 'new_email@email.com',
);
// Set the data to be validated
$this->request->setMethod('PUT');

// Send the additional parameters
$this->request->setContent(json_encode($params));
```

This errs because the server is looking for the $params key "attribute", but the $params array on the server is empty -- none of $params were passed in. The same goes when I try

```
foreach ($params as $n => $v) {
    $this->routeMatch->setParam($n, $v);
}
```

and

```
foreach ($params as $n => $v) {
    $this->request->getQuery()->set($n, $v);
}
```

and

```
foreach ($params as $n => $v) {
    $this->request->getPost()->set($n, $v);
}
```

What is the proper way to send PUT parameters in zf2?

Comment: You can use `$this->request->getPost()->fromArray` instead of a foreach loop to copy the array

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Then

```
$this->request->setContent(json_encode($params));
```

works. THe only thing is that it broke all of my POST requests, which were using `getPost()->set($n,$v)`. I had to go back to each of those test and do the same setContent with them, then they passed as well.

Comment: To add the header, use the following code `$headers = new Headers();        $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-type', 'application/json');        $this->request->setHeaders($headers);`